# Removing URL styles with CSS + SEO

Tags: seo, css, url, xhtml

I want to display a grid of images 4x4 with thumbnails and a title above each of them. I want to highlight the thumbnail and title and add a hyperlink to it. This works well in our CMS.

I would like to therefore know if styling the URL using CSS will cause a negative impact to SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CSS doesn't affect SEO in any way.